# Jerking panels and pictureboxes in WAF (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, panel, picturebox, slide

Im working to develop an application thats going to run on some not-so-good as performance PC's. The application is done in VB.NET and i encountered some obstacles during my work.

The idea of the application is to allow the users to slide through some pages when they click with the mouse and drag (while the left click is pressed) to right (for browsing to the previous page) and to left (for browsing to the next page). Every page contains 4/6/9 panels with 4/6/9 pictureboxes with some gifs as images.

The issue is that when the user drag with the mouse to browse to a page, the panels and the pictureboxes jerks around when they are moved.

Is there any way that this can be fixed?

Here is the code that handles the slide part

```
    If i + speed < 1024 Then
        For j As Integer = 0 To nrOfGamesInTotal - 1
            totemGame.gamePanel(j).Left = totemGame.gamePanel(j).Left + direction * speed
            totemGame.gamePic(j).Left = totemGame.gamePic(j).Left + direction * speed
        Next
        i = i + speed
        Return True
    Else
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after smooth 2D graphics capability you will probably need to use either DirectX or XNA.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Visual-Basic-XNA-29cd4963

Comment: Direct2D was failling at installing. Dont know why, but the installer didnt even start to extract its files. XNA was doing nothing, but just to make the loading of my application harder. Im thinking to chage the version of DirectX.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, but you can't just load the XNA assembly to make your existing code work better.  You will have to reprogram the graphics to use either the DirectX or XNA libraries.